# matplotlib how is a figure structured?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to understand how a figure is structured. My understanding is the following:

you have a canvas (if you've got a gui or something similar), a figure, and axes

you add the axes to the figure, and the figure to the canvas.

The plot is held by the axes, so for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2], [1, 4])
fig.show()
```

I would expect would create a figure however I just get a blank window... Also, it seems `canvas` is not needed at all?

any help appreciated thank you!

here it says the above code should work... or has a similar example

https://github.com/thehackerwithin/PyTrieste/wiki/Python7-MatPlotLib

Comment: What backend are you using, because that code should have worked.

Comment: when running `matplotlib.get_backend()` I get `'Qt4Agg'`

Comment: Your code runs correctly on my system, I suspect you have a configuration issue someplace.

Comment: hm... strange thing going on... I'm running it from spyder and it doesn't work. If i run it from a terminal and run ipython it works as expected!

Comment: I don't know much about spyder, but my _guess_ is that you are running into issues with the QT event loop.  If you haven't gotten this sorted, I would ask a new question re why mpl and spyder don't play nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be poking at the canvas unless you *really* know what you are doing (and are embedding mpl into another program).  `pyplot` has a bunch of nice tools that takes care of most of the set up for you.

There is a separation between the user layer (figures, axes, artists, and such) and the rendering layer (canvas, renderer, and such).  The first layer is user facing and should be machine independent.  The second layer is machine specific, but should expose none of that to 
the user.

There are a varity of 'backends' that take care of the translation between the two layers (by providing sub-classes of canvas and such).  There are interactive backends (QtAgg, GtkAgg, TkAgg,...) which include all the hooks into a gui toolkit to provide nice windows and non-interactive backend (PS, pdf, ...) that only save files.

`figure`s hold `axes` which hold `artists` (and `axis`).  Those classes will talk to the rendering layer, but you (for the most part) do not need to worry about exactly how.